# How to check duplicates in an entire Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to accomplish something perhaps to ambitious but perhaps you could give me a hand.

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 4 Sheets:

> Master Senpai | Chevez San | Gabbie Sama | Mario Chan

"Master Senpai" is a sheet with Consolidated data meaning everything in the other 3 sheets is within "Master Senpai"

These spreadsheet is currently being use by 3 coworkers (as you might guess Chevez Gabbie and Mario) what I need is for each of them to have the ability to confirm or check if any of the info they are inputting is duplicated.

All the Sheets have the same headers from A to L (12 Columns total) I want to check the duplicates for Column J.

So for Example if Mario Want to know if the info he just inputted Gabbie or Chevez has already put it I want that cell to get Formated with a red background.

Basically read the info from the last 3 sheets (Ignore the "Master Senpai" sheet) and check for duplicates if any found color them with a red background.

I've been reading about it and found something similar to what I'm trying to do.

```
/**
 * Finds duplicate rows in the active sheet and colors them red,
 but only pays attention to the indicated columns.
 */

function findDuplicates() {
  // List the columns you want to check by number (A = 1)
  var CHECK_COLUMNS = [2,3,5,6];

  // Get the active sheet and info about it
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var numCols = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  // Create the temporary working sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet("FindDupes");

  // Copy the desired rows to the FindDupes sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < CHECK_COLUMNS.length; i++) {
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,CHECK_COLUMNS[i],numRows);
    var nextCol = newSheet.getLastColumn() + 1;
    sourceRange.copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1,nextCol,numRows));
  }

  // Find duplicates in the FindDupes sheet and color them in the main sheet
  var dupes = false;
  var data = newSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
      if  (data[i].join() == data[j].join()) {
        dupes = true;
        sourceSheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,numCols).setBackground("red");
        sourceSheet.getRange(j+1,1,1,numCols).setBackground("red");
      }
    }
  }

  // Remove the FindDupes temporary sheet
  ss.deleteSheet(newSheet);

  // Alert the user with the results
  if (dupes) {
    Browser.msgBox("Possible duplicate(s) found and colored red.");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found.");
  }
};

/**
 * Adds a custom menu to the active spreadsheet
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Find Duplicates",
    functionName : "findDuplicates"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("My Scripts", entries);

  fillFormulas();
};
```

However this only looks for duplicates in the same sheet what I'm trying to accomplish is to read and compare the info from the last 3 sheets.

Comment: You would first need to come up with the logic of how the code would accomplish this, and how to deal with all possible different situations.  If you combined the data from all three sheets, then found a duplicate, how do you know where the duplicate came from?  Or do you combine the data of all sheets who aren't the current user?  Or do you not combine any data, and check each sheet of other users one at a time?  If you do that, then you must know who the current user is.  How are you going to do that?  You're basically asking a database design question.

Comment: Well the logic would be to analyze the data not compiled (Excluding the sheet where the information is compiled), when running the code I want to read the info on Column J (10th Column) from all 3 Sheets (Again ignoring  the "Master Senpai" Sheet) and if Duplicates are found to mark it regardless of who the author is or who ran the code. Mark all instances of a repeted cell value i.e. if on "Chevez San" I have Apple on Column J row 4 ([J4],{R5C10}) and on "Mario Chan" we have Apple on Column J row 1 ([J1],{R1C10}) I want both cells to be formatted with a red background when I run the code.

Comment: Start with the simplest thing you need to do.  You need to somehow get data out of a particular sheet.  You can get the sheet by name.  [Google Documentation - getSheetByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))

Comment: Add attribution for that code - it can help others understand it, and is just the right thing to do. It's by Carl Kranich, and also appeared in [this blog post](http://ctrlq.org/code/19649-find-duplicate-rows-in-google-sheets).